# Return different reponse or data depending on method - Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

Please help. What I need to do is to get different responses or data depending on the method- something like this:

> if request.method == 'POST':
>
> return all
> the items created including the last one (actually it returns only >the last item created)
>
> else if request.method == 'PUT':
>
> return the last item updated

Views.py

```
class RubroViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rubro.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RubroSerializer
```

models.py

```
class Rubro(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Rubros'
        db_table = "core_rubros"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

serializers.py

```
class RubroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rubro
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Is the example provided in the documentation sufficient? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using viewsets.Viewset would be an easy way.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

or use @detail_route()

```
    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def some_method(self, request):
        serializer = RubroSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'status': 'success'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually viewset allows you to implement `create` and `update` methods in viewset to control logic of different types of request. In your case you can do something like this:

```
class RubroViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rubro.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RubroSerializer

    # POST
    def create(self, request):
        super().create(request)
        serializer = self.serializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    # PUT
    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        return super().update(request, pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.Way:**
You could use "yield" instead "return".
This may be support...

**2.Way:**

```
def __str__(self):
    for n in self:
         return self.n
```